# Getting an error while installing supervisord on ubuntu 11.04. Any way to fix this?

Tags: debian, python, aptitude, ubuntu-11.04, supervisord

```
# aptitude install supervisor
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-medusa{a} python-meld3{a} supervisor 
0 packages upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/290 kB of archives. After unpacking 1,552 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
Selecting previously deselected package python-medusa.
(Reading database ... 35128 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking python-medusa (from .../python-medusa_0.5.4+clean-2ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package python-meld3.
Unpacking python-meld3 (from .../python-meld3_0.6.5-3build1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package supervisor.
Unpacking supervisor (from .../supervisor_3.0a8-1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up python-medusa (0.5.4+clean-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python-meld3 (0.6.5-3build1) ...
Setting up supervisor (3.0a8-1) ...
Starting supervisor: /usr/bin/supervisord:5: UserWarning: Module supervisor was already     imported from None, but /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7 is being added to sys.path
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
Error: No config file found at default paths (/usr/etc/supervisord.conf,     /usr/supervisord.conf, supervisord.conf, etc/supervisord.conf, /etc/supervisord.conf); use the     -c option to specify a config file at a different path
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
invoke-rc.d: initscript supervisor, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing supervisor (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for python-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 supervisor
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up supervisor (3.0a8-1) ...
Starting supervisor: /usr/bin/supervisord:5: UserWarning: Module supervisor was already   imported from None, but /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7 is being added to sys.path
  from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
Error: No config file found at default paths (/usr/etc/supervisord.conf,      /usr/supervisord.conf, supervisord.conf, etc/supervisord.conf, /etc/supervisord.conf); use the           -c option to specify a config file at a different path
For     help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
invoke-rc.d: initscript supervisor, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing supervisor (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 supervisor
```

Not sure why it isn't able to find the supervisord config file or why installation is failing. I did run aptitude update, aptitude upgrade, so hopefully everything is up to date :(

Answer (score 6):

I've just stumbled across the same issue, so I'll leave the reasons it happened to me.

We had supervisor installed into the global path (not a virtualenv) using pip, which meant we were running the latest version. However, this is undesirable from a server maintenance point of view, so we switched the older version in Apt.

`pip uninstall` doesn't clear up after itself properly, leaving scripts/logs in all the following directories:

- /usr/local/bin/
- /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
- /tmp/
- /etc/

I suggest doing the following search and manually removing all references to **supervisor-3.0a12**:

`sudo find / -iname "*supervisor*"`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. This is a bug currently not known. While installing you should receive a way different error because supervisor is currently broken in this version of Ubuntu. See the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/supervisor/+bug/777862

Answer (score 0):

supervisor was probably previsouly installed then removed but not purged (so the configuration files were not removed).  At some point later, someone removed the configuration file by hand.  Now when you reinstall, it will not replace the configuration file by default since dpkg never wants to overwrite a configuration change that you have made, and removing a configuration file is considered a configuration change.  You can tell dpkg specifically to replace missing conffiles like this:

```
aptitude -o DPkg::Options::='--force-confmiss' reinstall supervisor
```

Alternatively, you can purge the package before installing to say that you don't want to save your configuration files.